# SQL - Insert into a table for a specific list of IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a Select statement that returns a list of primary key (user_id).

```
select user_id from myttable
where <some-condition>;
```

Then I would like to insert a new row for each of those returned IDs from the previous Select. Can I do this in a single SQL Query? Can it be something like this? It looks a lot like I would need a loop in here somehow.

```
insert into mytable 
values (user_id, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
where user_id in 
(select user_id from myttable
    where <some-condition>)
```

`value1, value2, ..., value5` are the same for all the insert(s), except for `user_id`.
I could have done "update" instead of insert, but I need to keep the old rows for some other purpose.

So far what I did is was I just got a list of user_id(s), and in Java, went through that list and do insert one by one.

Comment: You have three values in your insert statement, but you're only selecting one from the table. Where do the other two come from?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just modified the statement. Basically, the value1, ..., value5 are the same for all the insert(s), except for user_id.

Answer (score 6):

```
insert into mytable(user_id,col1,col2) 
select user_id,'static_val1','static_val2' 
from myttable
where <some-condition>
```

Comment: needs an example of what "some-condition" could be

Comment: any valid where clause

Answer (score 2):

If value1 ... value5 are literal values, you can just do the following:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT id, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 FROM mytable WHERE <some-condition>
```

Comment: you should be explicit about the values you are entering otherwise that would be a bug waiting to happen....  `insert into mytable(id, value1, value2, value3...) select id, value1, value2, value3... `